# Can anyone give example of using sockets to send file?

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-7, winsock

I need to create two programs:

1. Server
2. Client

The server sends request to client, then the client receives request and captures the screen using this function:

```
function GetScreenShot(PixelFormat:TPixelFormat;Width,Height:Integer): TBitmap;
var
  Desktop: HDC;
begin
  Result  := TBitmap.Create;
  Desktop := GetDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
    try
      Result.PixelFormat := PixelFormat;
      Result.Width := Width;
      Result.Height := Height;
      BitBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height, Desktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      Result.Modified := True;
    finally
      ReleaseDC(0, Desktop);
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;
```

After that client sends bitmap to server.

Can someone help me?

---

<sub>*Edited to add:*</sub>

I have some examples:

- [This works](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/internet/send_a_file_from_a_tserversocket_to_a_tclientsocket.html)
- [This works too](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/201007/1007079821.html)
- [C++ and Delphi](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/projects/links/sockets.html)

Comment: Where is the bitmap file :) ?

Comment: What bitmap? This one-->? Bit:TBitmap; Bit:=TBitMap.Create;Bit.Assign(GetScreenShot(pf32bit,screen.width,screen.height));Bit.SaveToFile('thebit.bmp'); Bit.Free; But how to send?

Comment: Indy has `Write(AStream: TStream; ASize: TIdStreamSize = 0;
 AWriteByteCount: Boolean = False);` and `WriteFile(const AFile: String; AEnableTransferFile: Boolean)` in the TIdIOHandler component class

Comment: Isn't `GetDC(GetDesktopWindow)` better than `GetDC(0)`?

Comment: You could take a look at the [TWinHTTP and THttpApiServer classes](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrtSock.pas) which implements HTTP/1.1 communication via direct API: the server part is faster than WinSock because runs in Kernel mode. There are some pure WinSock functions and classes in the same Open Source unit.

Comment: @Robrok: I didn't downvote either, but this is not an answer. Any external website is not necessarily stable just because you say they are; delphitricks, for instance, could go down at any time if the owner decides not to renew it. And "google it" isn't an answer at all here.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this example http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa012004a.htm ?

Comment: Indy lets you use sockets on the same computer just fine. Is it Indy specifically that you don't like, or do you want to avoid using any third party components?

Comment: Well, sometimes it is even easier to use the plain Windows API, because that one is often more primitive, reliable, tested, and well-designed than a third-party API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never worked with WinSock directly, so I cannot post an answer right now. But if I get time over, I might attempt to write some code. Otherwise, I am sure that RRUZ, Rob Kennedy, David Heffernan, Mason Wheeler, Ken White, or some other Delphi expert can be of assistance.

Comment: Sorry for yelling, but TServerSocket and TClientSocket is the easiest answer. I use WinSockets because they are wery easy to code.I don`t know why but i have problems using Indy. It`s not connecting. :(

Comment: @Robrok Does this mean that you have solved your problem now?

Comment: Robrok - It would be much easier to select a trusted and tested component set (Indy, or ICS, or others) than to build on to of TServerSocket, and TClientSocket. Especially when you get to wanting to build complex servers and clients on top of them.  You might think it's "Easiest" now, but you'll change your mind later.  If you don't go crazy first.

Comment: Why not? Using WinSock can send files and text. WinSock is working. I have tested my application on both computers. Client sends file and server receives it.

Comment: Indy doesn`t work for me. Connection problems. I will use WinSock.

Comment: @Robrok - everybody would like to see your work. make an 'example' project and post it. In this way it will appreciated, improved, and all of of us can learn from it. keep the good work!